# Delete all rows in a Fusion Table at a specified time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I was wondering does anyone know of a way of deleting all rows from a fusion table at a specified time automatically i.e. 11:59pm all rows will be erased.

I am currently building an app for a college project on App Inventor 2 which involves people logging in and their name is then saved to the fusion table. As people will forget to log out I would like to be able to automatically delete all details from the table so it starts a fresh each day.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.
Michael

Comment: you could take a look into [Google Apps Script and the Fusion Table Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables), however I'm not sure if the [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers) also work for fusiontables...

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help. Will have a look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you can create a separate app running in the background checking time every hour and after 11 pm everyminute. And it will delete data at 11.59pm.
If you dont wanna dedicate a device for this, implement this in the original app and hope that at least one person will not clear all the apps that runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a google app script (GAS) that has a time-based trigger (set to run once a day, whatever time you like).  That script would connect with your FT (by the FT's ID) and do whatever you want (you can write semi-normal SQL queries, etc. to figure out which rows are to be deleted).  That said, I am working on an issue right now doing something similar and have found out that you can't issue normal sql to delete rows based on time-expressions, etc. (e.g., delete all rows older than 10 days does not work in GAS with FTs)  But, if you can determine which of your rows are to be deleted, you can delete them one at a time with GAS.